# Inertia group of function field

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification, function-fields

Let $C(T)$ be a function field in the variable $T$ over an algebraically closed field
$C$ of characteristic $0$.

Consider L as the splitting field for the following polynomial:

$F(X,T) = f(X)-T$

for $f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^r(X- \alpha_i)^{e_i}$

$\alpha_i \in C$

$e_i >= 1$

I know that the inertia group of primes of L above $(T)$ is cyclic with order $lcm(e_1, \dots, e_r)$

My question is:

Is that true for $C$ with $char(C) != 0$ ?

If it doesn't, please help me find some counter example.

Thank's!

Comment: No exactly i did it by finding $Gal(L_\mathfrak{P}/ K_T)$ which equal to the 
inertia group since the quotient field is K which is 
algebraically closed. $(K = C(T))$

Comment: When $C = \Bbb{C}$ the Galois group is the monodromy group, that is how a solution $f(T)$ (analytic around $T= z_0$) transforms when continuing analytically on closed curves. Around $a$ you have $f(a+T) = \sum_{k \ge -K} c_kT^{k/n}$ and a closed-loop around $a$ sends it to $\sum_{k \ge -K} c_k e^{2i \pi k/n}T^{k/n}$. The same holds for other fields coprime with all those ramification $n$. The monodromy is an algebraic tool.

Comment: So you it's true even for $Char(C) = p $ ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the monodromy theory, can you give some place to look for a reference?